# Bit Shifting & Manipulation

Tags: c

I'm trying to work with bit manipulation, and am struggling modifying the bits directly.

I have something as follows:

```
unsigned char myBits = 128; // 10000000 in binary
myBits = myBits >> 1; // Right shift, so we get 64, or 01000000 in binary
```

Now, how would I use bit manipulation to modify the first bit after the right shift (01000000) to a 1 (11000000)?

Comment: Ah right, typo thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most implementations will shift a "1" bit in from the left if the type in question is signed and the value is negative.

So you could either change the type to `signed char`, or do some casting on the unsigned types:

```
myBits = (unsigned char)((signed char)myBits >> 1);
```

Comment: it is very implementation defined.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'd like to know how to put either a `1` or `0` in the left most position of the bit after right shift, so I thought separating the logic would be easier

Comment: @nalabof679 To left shift in a 0, make sure the value is unsigned.

Comment: So to right shift and insert a `1` at the start, I would do `myBits = (unsigned char)((signed char)myBits >> 1);` -- how would I modify this with inserting a `0` with a right shift instead? I'm trying to understand this, sorry for the clarification question

Comment: @nalabof679 Given that the type is unsigned, just do what you're already doing.

Comment: Ah, I saw from another commentor that to insert a `0`, all I need to do is rightshift. So what's the difference between this implementation and the one below (`myBits |= myBits >> 1;`)?

Comment: @nalabof679 It's incorrect, as it can set additional bits if more than one is set.

Answer (score 0):

you need to binary OR it with the shifted value:

```
myBits |= myBits >> 1;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dY3eY5dc5

To set the most significant bit (you can change the type to any integer type and it will work):

```
myBits |= 1ULL << (sizeof(myBits) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
```

Comment: So is CHAR_BIT = 0 and = 1, depending on what I want to insert at the front (first bit, left most) AFTER the right shift?

Comment: @nalabof679 I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: I'd like to 1) right shift and 2)insert either a 0 or a 1 in the left most bit after the right shift. So how could I change your statement based on if I want to insert a `0` or a `1` after in the right shift into the left most bit position?

Comment: @nalabof679 To "insert a zero" you just right shift an unsigned type. Please clarify if the "insert a 1" case depends on the actual last bit `myBits` or not.

Comment: Ah... misunderstanding on my part. So if I want to insert a 1, I just `myBits |= myBits >> 1;`